# JSoup grab value that constantly changes

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to grab the value from the following HTML which constantly changes

```html
<span class="rts-counter" rel="current_population">
    <span class="rts-nr-sign"></span>
    <span class="rts-nr-int rts-nr-10e9">7</span>
    <span class="rts-nr-thsep">,</span>
    <span class="rts-nr-int rts-nr-10e6">786</span>
    <span class="rts-nr-thsep">,</span>
    <span class="rts-nr-int rts-nr-10e3">396</span>
    <span class="rts-nr-thsep">,</span>
    <span class="rts-nr-int rts-nr-10e0">227</span>
</span>
```

My code so far doesn't produce anything

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/").get();
        Elements div = doc.select("div.maincounter-number");
        Elements span = div.select("span");
        System.out.println(span);
```

Output. The stuff I want is in the ...

```
<span class="rts-counter" rel="current_population">retrieving data... </span>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to have anything to do with the span fest that you posted from the World population website.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yeah I was messing around hoping I can get the values. div.maincounter-number encompasses the section of the code that I actually want

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Jsoup, but you have to traverse the HTML to get to the elements you want.  Formatting the HTML you get from the website will help you to see the structure that you have to traverse.  As far as the question in your title, first, get your code to work.  Second, call your code periodically.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yes I was going down that path. I got the following

<span class="rts-counter" rel="current_population">retrieving data... </span>

the stuff is in the ... which confuses me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common for sites with dynamic content to use a placeholder as

```
<span class="rts-counter" rel="current_population">retrieving data... </span>
```

so this span can be filled with data later. Usually after executing another asynchronous request to server to load only the data that is changing.
Jsoup can't execute JavaScript but it's usually possible to make a direct call for additional data resources usually returned as JSON. But here it won't work and I have bad news...
**The data you see is fake!** I'm monitoring this site with Chrome's debugger and checking Network tab I see there's no communication with server and there's no data that's dynamically fetched. That means the data is retrieved only on first load and then JavaScript and some mathematical formula is used to increase the counters by a certain value after a certain time has passed giving it a bit of randomness to make it look convincing.
Initial data values are downloaded using this URL:
https://www.realtimestatistics.net/rts/init.php?callback=jsoncallback&host=worldometers&time=1590244162325&_=1590244161401 (link is dynamic and probaby expired by now)
but the result is somehow encoded. It seems to be decoded in this script https://www.realtimestatistics.net/rts/RTSp.js but it's minimized and hard to read.

So the get the original value you'd have to reverse engineer and analyze their RTSp.js to obtain initial value and the formula they're using to increment the counter.

Related info https://www.worldometers.info/licensing/what/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information! I see that's why it shows up ... in the HTML, I was thinking this is the first time I've encountered such problem. Do you think using Selenium can fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, Selenium can evaluate JavaScript so you should always get the current calculated value. But to be honest I don't see a reason why you need so accurate value when even this site admits the value is just result of analyzing some models and it's not the real value. You can also fake it and add +3 every second and the result will be more or less similar :)